# .Net core - How to create multi-platform executable from a console app

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm starting to work with .net core 1.1 on a Web API project. The way I'm currently starting my server for the API is by publishing with `dotnet publish` and then running with `dotnet MyProject.dll`. Now I have a requirement to start the server from an executable file on Windows and on Linux. I wrote a .net core console app that does just that but the question is how do I wrap in in an executable file for .exe for Windows and what ever it is for Linux...?

Comment: Reading the docs is always a good first start: [Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs#simpleSelf)

Comment: Thank for the link, it was exactly what I needed. Would you like to post it as an answer so I'll mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just entering the link given in the comment, to mark it as the correct answer.
 [Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs#simpleSelf)